# How to hide Today widget on app first run?

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I'm wondering how to hide a Today widget on the app's first run.

I don't want to hide it from `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` but rather from the widget's `info.plist` or lifecycle methods in order to decouple the `AppDelegate` from widget logic.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by hide it?

Comment: @RashwanL I mean not showing it to the user. It's possible using the `setHasContent:forWidgetWithBundleIdentifier:` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NotificationCenter/Reference/NCWidgetController_Class/index.html)

> Typically, a widget appears in the Today view when it has content to
>   display. If a currently running widget no longer has content to
>   display, it can get a widget controller and set to false the flag in
>   the setHasContent:forWidgetWithBundleIdentifier: method.

What you could do is to do the following:

Check by `NSUserDefaults` if it´s the first time the app is running and in the set setHasContent:forWidgetWithBundleIdentifier to false. Code example below:

```
if !NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("firstRun"){
    // first run so do set setHasContent:forWidgetWithBundleIdentifier to false

    // Set your NSUserDefaults firstRun value to false so it does not run again
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "firstRun")
}
```

Comment: I added this code in my widget's VC's `viewDidLoad()`, not in the app's `AppDelegate` (this was what I was looking for). The only difference is that I used `NSUserDefaults(suiteName: <yourSuiteName>)` and don't know if you can rely on the `standardUserDefaults()` in the widget code.

Comment: Yes it is as you have added it, if you need sample code I can help you with that too.

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru I approved your edit because it is an answer related to your question, but please if you are tempted to change something fundamental that doesn't look like s typo, write a comment first and wait a day for an answer. This is the standard here for new answers and answers with more upvotes. Consider that in rare cases you can be wrong.

Comment: This method is deprecated, what is the wayaround for this in latest WidgetKit ?

Comment: @Mrunal, what do you mean by deprecated the syntax or the method of doing this?

Comment: @RashwanL Apple docs suggests to use WidgetKit instead of deprecated NCWidgetController - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls8XC.png